# Conditional join of query using PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a case where I need to run different query in join per function variable

Currently I have a function as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION a(type_f boolean)
  RETURNS SETOF rowtypes AS
$$
declare row rowtypes ;
begin   
....
select...
from..
left join (select pp.a, avg(ppp.priceusd) as avgpricetf
           from pp
           join p on (p.b=pp.b)
           join (...) as ppp on (pp.c=p.c)
           group by pp.a) tfquery on (tfquery.a=main.a)
....
end;
$$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
```

This works fine.

I want to modify it so when `type_f=True` this query will run in the join instad of the original one:

```
left join (select pp.a,p.d, avg(ppp.priceusd) as avgpricetf
           from pp
           join p on (p.b=pp.b)
           join (...) as ppp on (pp.c=p.c)
           group by pp.a,p.d) tfquery on (tfquery.a=main.a and tfquery.d=main.d)
```

As you can see the query is changed as well as the condition of the join itself.

**Basicly**:

When `type_f=False` do:

```
left join (select pp.a, avg(ppp.priceusd) as avgpricetf
           from pp
           join p on (p.b=pp.b)
           join (...) as ppp on (pp.c=p.c)
           group by pp.a) tfquery on (tfquery.a=main.a)
```

When:
`type_f=True` do:

```
left join (select pp.a,p.d, avg(ppp.priceusd) as avgpricetf
           from pp
           join p on (p.b=pp.b)
           join (...) as ppp on (pp.c=p.c)
           group by pp.a,p.d) tfquery on (tfquery.a=main.a and tfquery.d=main.d)
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use logic like this to kill all possible readability to your query and get expected results:

```
Select *
from A
left outer join
   ( select * from B where type_f
     union all
     select *, A.field from C where not type_f
   ) X
on X.n = A.n and X.field = A.field
....
```

Comment: but the  `on... ` is diffrent between them.

Comment: @Tov3, yes, you can append a fake field from outer table.

Comment: @Tov3, or you can compose an expression: `( type_f and condition1) or ( not type_f and condition2 ) `

Comment: You can not define diffrent selects types when you use UNION. so You cant do   `select * from ... uinon select *,A.field from`.  Also  I cant add `,p.d` to the select of the first query. it doesn't work with the `GROUP BY`. SO i don't see how the union can work

Comment: @Tov3, of course man, you should to select right fields and types.